# Windows Phone 8/OAuth: Is it possible to redirect from the native browser to an app?

Tags: redirect, windows-phone-8, oauth

I need to use the native browser (IE) of Windows Phone 8 for Quizlet authentication. Quizlet does not allow browser control, but if I use Internet Explorer I don't know how to redirect to my app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for [custom URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_URIassociations).

Set the redirection URL to something like "yourapp://" in the OAuth settings of Quizlet, register a custom URI scheme and parse the OAuth token in your app.

The absolutely best way would be to use the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025) which is kind of a embedded browser control but without the app having access to it. It was kind of designed for OAuth login flows where apps shouldn't have access to the website. Users still don't have to leave the app and have auto-fill. I don't know why Quizlet should not allow this method.

Comment: The WebAuthenticationBroker is currently only available for Windows Store apps. Not for Windows Phone. But I'm going to take at look at the custom URI schemes.

Comment: True, but why would you still target WP8? WP8.1 Silverlight apps have support for as well, see: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-use-0